# How to group by the following aliased column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, group-by

How would you group by the aliased column `Test_Quarter` on the following query:

```
SELECT  a.testID, 
        a.projectYear ,
        CASE a.ProjectPeriod
            WHEN 1 THEN 1
            WHEN 2 THEN 1
            WHEN 3 THEN 1
            WHEN 4 THEN 2
            WHEN 5 THEN 2
            WHEN 6 THEN 2
            WHEN 7 THEN 3
            WHEN 8 THEN 3
            WHEN 9 THEN 3
            WHEN 10 THEN 4
            WHEN 11 THEN 4
            WHEN 12 THEN 4 
        END AS Test_Quarter,
        SUM(a.cost)
FROM    test a
GROUP   BY a.testID, a.projectYear, Test_Quarter
```

Thank you,

Comment: You can use same as a.Test_Quarter or place all case statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include Case Statement in Group by Clause

```
SELECT  a.testID, 
        a.projectYear ,
        CASE a.ProjectPeriod
            WHEN 1 THEN 1
            WHEN 2 THEN 1
            WHEN 3 THEN 1
            WHEN 4 THEN 2
            WHEN 5 THEN 2
            WHEN 6 THEN 2
            WHEN 7 THEN 3
            WHEN 8 THEN 3
            WHEN 9 THEN 3
            WHEN 10 THEN 4
            WHEN 11 THEN 4
            WHEN 12 THEN 4 
        END AS Test_Quarter,
        SUM(a.cost)
FROM    test a
GROUP   BY a.testID, a.projectYear, CASE a.ProjectPeriod
            WHEN 1 THEN 1
            WHEN 2 THEN 1
            WHEN 3 THEN 1
            WHEN 4 THEN 2
            WHEN 5 THEN 2
            WHEN 6 THEN 2
            WHEN 7 THEN 3
            WHEN 8 THEN 3
            WHEN 9 THEN 3
            WHEN 10 THEN 4
            WHEN 11 THEN 4
            WHEN 12 THEN 4 
        END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.testID, 
        a.projectYear ,
        CASE a.ProjectPeriod
            WHEN 1 THEN 1
            WHEN 2 THEN 1
            WHEN 3 THEN 1
            WHEN 4 THEN 2
            WHEN 5 THEN 2
            WHEN 6 THEN 2
            WHEN 7 THEN 3
            WHEN 8 THEN 3
            WHEN 9 THEN 3
            WHEN 10 THEN 4
            WHEN 11 THEN 4
            WHEN 12 THEN 4 
        END AS Test_Quarter,
        SUM(a.cost)
FROM    test a
GROUP   BY a.testID, a.projectYear,CASE a.ProjectPeriod
            WHEN 1 THEN 1
            WHEN 2 THEN 1
            WHEN 3 THEN 1
            WHEN 4 THEN 2
            WHEN 5 THEN 2
            WHEN 6 THEN 2
            WHEN 7 THEN 3
            WHEN 8 THEN 3
            WHEN 9 THEN 3
            WHEN 10 THEN 4
            WHEN 11 THEN 4
            WHEN 12 THEN 4 
        END
```